# Epplus Format Cell as Time error

Tags: c#, epplus

I use `LoadFromCollection` to import data.

Everything is fine but I have problems with formatting cell type `HH:mm`

Base value: `5/2/2018 14:15:00`

My format:

```
workSheet.Cells["K11"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "HH:mm"
```

After exporting the excel file

In Dev PC(Window 10, Visual Studio 2017): `14:15` . Base value of excel cell: `5/2/2018  14:15:00`

In Server(Window Server 2012, IIS): `02:15` . Base value of excel cell: `5/2/2018  02:15:00`

Please let me know my code is wrong or bug of Epplus. Thank!

Comment: Maybe you have to change your server's long date format to 24 hour in the regional settings of the server

Comment: @FaridImranov I changed the configuration of two machines the same but still error.

Comment: Maybe this works `Style.Numberformat.Format = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortTimePattern`

Comment: @VDWWD thank you. But still error.